# While Loop Not Recognizing Input

Tags: c++

I'm at a loss of what to do here.
So I have this simple while loop meant to allow a user to re-input a number if they accidentally give an incorrect input.
The issue is, if you input "2" it loops back again. I can't, for the life of me figure it out.

```
void Player::playerPick()
{
    int selection = 0;
    while (selection != (1 || 2))
    {
        cout << "Player 1 or Player 2 (Type [1] or [2])";
        cin >> selection;
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (selection != 1 && selection != 2)`

Comment: `(1 || 2)` is `true`. You wrote `while(selection != true)`. Many compilers issue a warning.

Comment: Might be difficult to find the duplicate, but this has been asked before.

Comment: @crashmstr: The usual mistake is `(selection!=1 || 2)`. That's _not_ a duplicate because it means `((selection!=1) || 2)`

Comment: @MSalters I would argue that even though the result here is different due to the parentheses, the underlying misunderstanding of comparison operators is still the same (this person just tried `()`), and that the answer is also fundamentally the same.

Answer (score 4):

You wrote:

```
while (selection != (1 || 2))
```

This is "while selection is not one or two".

The actual correct English is "while selection is neither one nor two", and that's true in C++ also:

```
while (!(selection == 1 || selection == 2))
```

Or, simpler, "while selection is not one, and selection is not two":

```
while (selection != 1 && selection != 2)
```

The expression `1 || 2` evaluates to `true`, so you wrote `while (selection != true)`, which is the case for *any* non-zero value of `selection`.